# ASP.NET MVC Integração de contas com autenticação office365

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto em Asp.net MVC 4 e os usuários fizeram o registro pelo próprio sistema, porem surgiu a necessidade fazer a autenticação deles pelo office365, ou seja, ao acessar o office365 o sistema reconhecer o mesmo email de acesso e integrar, para não precisar efetuar o login, mas caso o usuário queira conectar com a senha antiga ele permita efetuar o mesmo.

Comment: Não entendi qual a dúvida que está tendo.

Comment: Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por esse tipo de situação

Comment: Provavelmente sim. Mas esse tipo de pergunta foge do escopo do site. Se fosse uma dúvida de como fazer ou algo do tipo, poderíamos até ajudara. Mas, de qualquer forma, [olhe este projeto](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start#questions-and-comments). Ele possui um exemplo de como utilizar a [API do Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview).

Comment: Obrigado @Randrade  realmente você tem razão, estou continuando as pesquisas e caso tenha alguma duvida especifica, posto aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a autenticação dos usuários em seu sistema usando conta Office365, basta usar esse guia: [Walkthrough ASP.NET MVC Identity with Microsoft Account Authentication](http://www.benday.com/2014/02/25/walkthrough-asp-net-mvc-identity-with-microsoft-account-authentication/).

Mas não vai funcionar bem como eles esperam. Mesmo tendo os usuarios autenticados no Office365, quando acessarem seu sistema, terão que se autenticar usando as mesmas credenciais. Porém, nada que um `checkbox` "Lembrar de mim" não resolva. :)

Por último, não tem como continuarem usando a mesma senha do seu sistema e usarem a autenticação do Office365. Se irá usar o Office365, é ele quem irá gerir as autenticações, e não mais o seu sistema.

Caso quiser um código fácil de aproveitar, basta criar um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC no Visual Studio com template de Forms Authentication. Então vá na *controller* `AccountController` e veja as implementações.

No meu GitHub tem um exemplo inclusive com [Isolamento do ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/IdentityIsolation), pode ajudar.